# Dropzone.js -- Error when loading, weird long message

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

Im trying to do a simple dropzone file  uploader. Im not interested in the server side as Im not doing this seriously, just trying the js for the front end. Everything seems ok, the load bar works fine, but then it always show the X image and then I get this insanely long message that contains html.

This confuses me because from the examples ive seen, if there is an error it will display the string from the js. I dont know why it's showing this long message.

Does it have anything to do with the "action" or "file" type?

A screenshot is here
 https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13310379_496643860530613_5508631554600071626_n.jpg?oh=1c25de2a0cb0957a68c1e8e2905b52df&oe=57DC5CA0https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13310379_496643860530613_5508631554600071626_n.jpg?oh=1c25de2a0cb0957a68c1e8e2905b52df&oe=57DC5CA0

Edit:

My HTML is this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="assets/js/dropzone.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/dropzone-amd-module.js"></script>
    <link href="assets/css/dropzone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/css/basic.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/css/Style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="dropzone">
<form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="demo-upload">
    <div class="dz-default">

  <div class="fallback">
    <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
  </div>
        </div>
</form>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Question about dropzone and you haven't included the dropzone code. How can we help without it?

Comment: I just ysed the dropzone.js that is given in the documentation. I only added the link in the header. I will add it anyway

Comment: the js file is too long to add in the description however it is dropzone.js file listed here. https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/tree/master/dist

I added copied that text and created the js file in my local folder. and then linked it externally in the header as shown in the html

Answer (score 0):

My bad, didn't know you were using the default `Dropzone.js`. I'd remove the downvote if I could but it's locked in now.
Try

```
<form action="UploadImages" class="dropzone">
</form>
```

Remove the `<div id="dropzone">` too. You already specify dropzone for the form, so wrapping it in a div with id of dropzone makes no sense.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3zhyg73u/85/ so you can compare your code and see why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, Im pretty new to this but i think it's because the errorMessage from the error event receive's a string containing HTML when a failed post request is sent out. you can change the message by doing this. this isn't the best method but it works :/ ohh and i was using jquery for this particular project

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone('#icDropZone', {
        url: "/file/post",
        error: function(response, errorMessage, xhrObj) {
            if(response.status === "error") {
                $('div.dz-default.dz-message > span').show(); // Show message span
                $('div.dz-default.dz-message').css({'opacity':1, 'background-image': 'none'});
                $('.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-error-message').attr('style','display:block;opacity:1;top: 150px;background:#D44F4F;');
                $('.dropzone .dz-preview .dz-error-message span').html('Error uploading image')
            }
        }
    });
```